# Would it be worth to remove the .aspx/.ascx lookup if I don't plan to use them?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-3

Now that MVC 3 Preview 1 here, we can use Razor (.cshtml) view engine. If a view not found, I get this error:

```
The view 'a' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/a.aspx
~/Views/Home/a.ascx
~/Views/Shared/a.aspx
~/Views/Shared/a.ascx
~/Views/Home/a.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/a.cshtml
```

Would it be worth to remove the .aspx/.ascx lookup, if I don't plan to use them?

Comment: In an [MVC4 Jump Start video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Web-Apps-with-ASP-NET-Jump-Start/Building-Web-Apps-with-ASPNET-Jump-Start-02-Building-and-Deploying-Websites-with-ASPNET-MVC-4), Scott Hanselman says you might achieve a tiny performance improvement by doing this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I doubt you would gain any noticeable performance gain from that. It's merely a file check and if it's also cached by the engine there's hardly any performance improvement. I'd call it micro-optimization!

I guess if you know you won't be using WebForms, you could just remove it from the list of view engines, like so:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
```

That way it won't check for aspx/ascx files.

Comment: I would recomend the first option, since we (MVC team) are not currently comitting to any particular order of view engines in that collection.

Comment: @marcin: It's probably best to find the View Engines you don't want and manually remove them by locating their index and removing them. That way if MVC ever adds extra view engines (or other components register their own view engines) you won't be removing them.

Comment: True, thought about that too, but as he only wanted to use Cshtml I didn't add it. Could look something like this: `ViewEngines.Engines.Remove(ViewEngines.Engines.OfType<WebFormViewEngine>().First());`
Funny how many different ways you can write this!

Answer (score 4):

The Code has been revised:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
```